# Selecting the vendor with highest Ratio and lowest price per product

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, inner-join, min

From my Orders table I'm trying to get per product the vendor with the highest Ratio order and lowest price.

```
      select v.[Vendor_pk], p.[Product_pk],o.[UnitPrice], o.[RatioOrder], o.[TotalPrice]
  from [DWH].[ORDERSfact] o
  inner join [DWH].[VENDORdim] v
  on o.[Vendor_pk]=v.[Vendor_pk]
  inner join [DWH].[PRODUCTdim] p
  on o.[Product_pk]= p.[Product_pk]

  order by 2, 4 desc, 3
```

[image]

How can I do that here?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Show what you are able to do.

Comment: The parts of this are faqs.. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to get per product the vendor with the highest Ratio order and lowest price.

Use `row_number()`:

```
select vp.*
from (select v.[Vendor_pk], p.[Product_pk],o.[UnitPrice], o.[RatioOrder], o.[TotalPrice],
             row_number() over (partition by product_pk order by ratioorder desc, price asc) sa seqnum
      from [DWH].[ORDERSfact] o join
           [DWH].[VENDORdim] v
           on o.[Vendor_pk] = v.[Vendor_pk] join
           [DWH].[PRODUCTdim] p
           on o.[Product_pk] = p.[Product_pk]
     ) vp
where seqnum = 1;
```